# PHPExcel writes only one row

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am having trouble with PHPExcel library. I have writen some blocks of code where I write to excel document using library functions like setCellValue(), setCellValueExplicit(), or getCell()->setValue() (I tried all of these), but only the first row is written on excel document. If I comment the first piece of code where the first row is written, then only the second row of excel document is written, nothing below. It's strange because I have used this library successfylly in the past. Can someone help me?
Code:

```
    $xls_version = '5';
        $phpExcel = new PHPExcel();
        // Get the active sheet and assign to a variable
        $sheet = $phpExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setTitle('Estrazione dati');

        $col = array(
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
            'AF', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ',
            'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BK', 'BL', 'BM', 'BN', 'BO', 'BP', 'BQ', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BU', 'BV', 'BW', 'BX', 'BY', 'BZ',
            'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CJ', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CP', 'CQ', 'CR', 'CS', 'CT', 'CU', 'CV', 'CW', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ',
            'DA', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DF', 'DG', 'DH', 'DI', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DL', 'DM', 'DN', 'DO', 'DP', 'DQ', 'DR', 'DS', 'DT', 'DU', 'DV', 'DW', 'DX', 'DY', 'DZ',
            'EA', 'EB', 'EC', 'ED', 'EE', 'EF', 'EG', 'EH', 'EI', 'EJ', 'EK', 'EL', 'EM', 'EN', 'EO', 'EP', 'EQ', 'ER', 'ES', 'ET', 'EU', 'EV', 'EW', 'EX', 'EY', 'EZ',
            'FA', 'FB', 'FC', 'FD', 'FE', 'FF', 'FG', 'FH', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FK', 'FL', 'FM', 'FN', 'FO', 'FP', 'FQ', 'FR', 'FS', 'FT', 'FU', 'FV', 'FW', 'FX', 'FY', 'FZ',
            'GA', 'GB', 'GC', 'GD', 'GE', 'GF', 'GG', 'GH', 'GI', 'GJ', 'GK', 'GL', 'GM', 'GN', 'GO', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GS', 'GT', 'GU', 'GV', 'GW', 'GX', 'GY', 'GZ',
            'HA', 'HB', 'HC', 'HD', 'HE', 'HF', 'HG', 'HH', 'HI', 'HJ', 'HK', 'HL', 'HM', 'HN', 'HO', 'HP', 'HQ', 'HR', 'HS', 'HT', 'HU', 'HV', 'HW', 'HX', 'HY', 'HZ',
            'IA', 'IB', 'IC', 'ID', 'IE', 'IF', 'IG', 'IH', 'II', 'IJ', 'IK', 'IL', 'IM', 'IN', 'IO', 'IP', 'IQ', 'IR', 'IS', 'IT', 'IU', 'IV', 'IW', 'IX', 'IY', 'IZ',
            'JA', 'JB', 'JC', 'JD', 'JE', 'JF', 'JG', 'JH', 'JI', 'JJ', 'JK', 'JL', 'JM', 'JN', 'JO', 'JP', 'JQ', 'JR', 'JS', 'JT', 'JU', 'JV', 'JW', 'JX', 'JY', 'JZ',
            'KA', 'KB', 'KC', 'KD', 'KE', 'KF', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KJ', 'KK', 'KL', 'KM', 'KN', 'KO', 'KP', 'KQ', 'KR', 'KS', 'KT', 'KU', 'KV', 'KW', 'KX', 'KY', 'KZ',
            'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LD', 'LE', 'LF', 'LG', 'LH', 'LI', 'LJ', 'LK', 'LL', 'LM', 'LN', 'LO', 'LP', 'LQ', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LW', 'LX', 'LY', 'LZ',
            'MA', 'MB', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MF', 'MG', 'MH', 'MI', 'MJ', 'MK', 'ML', 'MM', 'MN', 'MO', 'MP', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MS', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ',
            'NA', 'NB', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NF', 'NG', 'NH', 'NI', 'NJ', 'NK', 'NL', 'NM', 'NN', 'NO', 'NP', 'NQ', 'NR', 'NS', 'NT', 'NU', 'NV', 'NW', 'NX', 'NY', 'NZ',
            'OA', 'OB', 'OC', 'OD', 'OE', 'OF', 'OG', 'OH', 'OI', 'OJ', 'OK', 'OL', 'OM', 'ON', 'OO', 'OP', 'OQ', 'OR', 'OS', 'OT', 'OU', 'OV', 'OW', 'OX', 'OY', 'OZ',
            'PA', 'PB', 'PC', 'PD', 'PE', 'PF', 'PG', 'PH', 'PI', 'PJ', 'PK', 'PL', 'PM', 'PN', 'PO', 'PP', 'PQ', 'PR', 'PS', 'PT', 'PU', 'PV', 'PW', 'PX', 'PY', 'PZ',
            'QA', 'QB', 'QC', 'QD', 'QE', 'QF', 'QG', 'QH', 'QI', 'QJ', 'QK', 'QL', 'QM', 'QN', 'QO', 'QP', 'QQ', 'QR', 'QS', 'QT', 'QU', 'QV', 'QW', 'QX', 'QY', 'QZ',
            'RA', 'RB', 'RC', 'RD', 'RE', 'RF', 'RG', 'RH', 'RI', 'RJ', 'RK', 'RL', 'RM', 'RN', 'RO', 'RP', 'RQ', 'RR', 'RS', 'RT', 'RU', 'RV', 'RW', 'RX', 'RY', 'RZ',
            'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SD', 'SE', 'SF', 'SG', 'SH', 'SI', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SO', 'SP', 'SQ', 'SR', 'SS', 'ST', 'SU', 'SV', 'SW', 'SX', 'SY', 'SZ',
            'TA', 'TB', 'TC', 'TD', 'TE', 'TF', 'TG', 'TH', 'TI', 'TJ', 'TK', 'TL', 'TM', 'TN', 'TO', 'TP', 'TQ', 'TR', 'TS', 'TT', 'TU', 'TV', 'TW', 'TX', 'TY', 'TZ',
            'UA', 'UB', 'UC', 'UD', 'UE', 'UF', 'UG', 'UH', 'UI', 'UJ', 'UK', 'UL', 'UM', 'UN', 'UO', 'UP', 'UQ', 'UR', 'US', 'UT', 'UU', 'UV', 'UW', 'UX', 'UY', 'UZ',
            'VA', 'VB', 'VC', 'VD', 'VE', 'VF', 'VG', 'VH', 'VI', 'VJ', 'VK', 'VL', 'VM', 'VN', 'VO', 'VP', 'VQ', 'VR', 'VS', 'VT', 'VU', 'VV', 'VW', 'VX', 'VY', 'VZ',
            'WA', 'WB', 'WC', 'WD', 'WE', 'WF', 'WG', 'WH', 'WI', 'WJ', 'WK', 'WL', 'WM', 'WN', 'WO', 'WP', 'WQ', 'WR', 'WS', 'WT', 'WU', 'WV', 'WW', 'WX', 'WY', 'WZ',
            'XA', 'XB', 'XC', 'XD', 'XE', 'XF', 'XG', 'XH', 'XI', 'XJ', 'XK', 'XL', 'XM', 'XN', 'XO', 'XP', 'XQ', 'XR', 'XS', 'XT', 'XU', 'XV', 'XW', 'XX', 'XY', 'XZ',
            'YA', 'YB', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YJ', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YO', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YU', 'YV', 'YW', 'YX', 'YY', 'YZ',
            'ZA', 'ZB', 'ZC', 'ZD', 'ZE', 'ZF', 'ZG', 'ZH', 'ZI', 'ZJ', 'ZK', 'ZL', 'ZM', 'ZN', 'ZO', 'ZP', 'ZQ', 'ZR', 'ZS', 'ZT', 'ZU', 'ZV', 'ZW', 'ZX', 'ZY', 'ZZ',
            'AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAD', 'AAE', 'AAF', 'AAG', 'AAH', 'AAI', 'AAJ', 'AAK', 'AAL', 'AAM', 'AAN', 'AAO', 'AAP', 'AAQ', 'AAR', 'AAS', 'AAT', 'AAU', 'AAV', 'AAW', 'AAX', 'AAY', 'AAZ',
            'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ABD', 'ABE', 'ABF', 'ABG', 'ABH', 'ABI', 'ABJ', 'ABK', 'ABL', 'ABM', 'ABN', 'ABO', 'ABP', 'ABQ', 'ABR', 'ABS', 'ABT', 'ABU', 'ABV', 'ABW', 'ABX', 'ABY', 'ABZ',
            'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'ACD', 'ACE', 'ACF', 'ACG', 'ACH', 'ACI', 'ACJ', 'ACK', 'ACL', 'ACM', 'ACN', 'ACO', 'ACP', 'ACQ', 'ACR', 'ACS', 'ACT', 'ACU', 'ACV', 'ACW', 'ACX', 'ACY', 'ACZ',
            'ADA', 'ADB', 'ADC', 'ADD', 'ADE', 'ADF', 'ADG', 'ADH', 'ADI', 'ADJ', 'ADK', 'ADL', 'ADM', 'ADN', 'ADO', 'ADP', 'ADQ', 'ADR', 'ADS', 'ADT', 'ADU', 'ADV', 'ADW', 'ADX', 'ADY', 'ADZ',
            'AEA', 'AEB', 'AEC', 'AED', 'AEE', 'AEF', 'AEG', 'AEH', 'AEI', 'AEJ', 'AEK', 'AEL', 'AEM', 'AEN', 'AEO', 'AEP', 'AEQ', 'AER', 'AES', 'AET', 'AEU', 'AEV', 'AEW', 'AEX', 'AEY', 'AEZ',
            'AFA', 'AFB', 'AFC', 'AFD', 'AFE', 'AFF', 'AFG', 'AFH', 'AFI', 'AFJ', 'AFK', 'AFL', 'AFM', 'AFN', 'AFO', 'AFP', 'AFQ', 'AFR', 'AFS', 'AFT', 'AFU', 'AFV', 'AFW', 'AFX', 'AFY', 'AFZ',
        );

        $i = 1;
        foreach ($arr_qa as $q=>$alternatives) {
            $first_col = $col[$i];
            $last_col = $col[$i + count($alternatives) - 1];
            $sheet->setCellValueExplicit($first_col.'1', $q)->mergeCells($first_col.'1' .':'. $last_col.'1');
               $i += count($alternatives);
        }
        $j = 1;
        foreach ($arr_qa as $q=>$alternatives) {
            foreach ($alternatives as $k=>$v) {
                $sheet->setCellValueExplicit($col[$j].'2', $v);
                $j++;
            }
        }

        $r = 3;
        foreach ($row as $id=>$ana) {
            $sheet->setCellValueExplicit("A$r", $ana['nome']);
//            echo '<br> '.'A'.$r.': ' . $ana['nome']. ' ';
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($arr_qa as $q=>$alternatives) {
                foreach ($alternatives as $k=>$v) {
                    if (!empty($ana['data'][$q.'_'.$v])) {
                        $sheet->setCellValueExplicit($col[$i].$r, 'X');
                        $this->writeLogFile(print_r([$col[$i].$r, $q.'_'.$v], true));
//                        echo $col[$i].$r.': '.'1 | ';
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            $r++;
        }

        for ($j=1; $j<=$r; $j++) {
            $sheet->getRowDimension($j)->setRowHeight(17);
        }

        $sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(25);

        //Set the active sheet to the first sheet before outputting. This is only needed if you want to ensure the file is opened on the first sheet.
        $phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        //Output the generated excel file so that the user can save or open the file.
        $x=''; if($xls_version=='2007') $x='x';
        $titolo = "EstrazioneDati";
        $path = $GLOBALS['ROOT_DATA'] . DS . "dati_excel". DS;
        $filename = $titolo . ".xls$x";
        $file = $path.$filename;

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel$xls_version");
        $objWriter->save($file);
        unset($objWriter);
        unset($phpExcel);
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I added the piece of code.

Comment: since we know the value of none of your objects you're iterating over all i an say is this `foreach ($row as $id=>$ana)` is probably returning only one row.

Comment: A mass of this code is here to get column addresses from numbers, why not reduce the sheer volume of code by using PHPExcel's built-in `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()` method instead

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution. At the beginning of code I just changed

```
$xls_version = '2007';
```

So there is probably a bug in PHPExcel library when writing complex arrays in old version of excel(xls), use instead 'xlsx' as extension.

Comment: No such bug exists in PHPExcel as far as I'm aware; if you believe that there is, then file an issue..... but provide a simple example to demonstrate any bug rather than the wall of code that you've provided here.... however, be aware that the old Excel BIFF format will discard any columns after IV, and any rows after 65535; those are Excel limitations